# Eigen lazy evaluation and temporaries: some case studies

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3, temporary-objects

Following the suggestions from this post [Identifying temporary object creation in Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918480/identifying-temporary-object-creation-in-eigen), I made some tests to understand when temporary Eigen objects are created.
This is the code used to identify temporaries:

```
static long int nb_temporaries;
inline void on_temporary_creation( long int size ) {
  if ( size != 0 ) nb_temporaries++;
}

#define EIGEN_DENSE_STORAGE_CTOR_PLUGIN { on_temporary_creation(size); }
```

All tests has been perfomed using VisualStudio 2017 (v15.9.20) with Eigen 3.3.7 and the following objects:

```
const int n = 100;
MatrixXd A( n, n );
VectorXd x( n );
VectorXd y( n );
VectorXd a( n );
VectorXd b( n );
Map<MatrixXd> A_map( A.data(), n, n );
Map<VectorXd> x_map( x.data(), n );
Map<VectorXd> y_map( y.data(), n );
Map<VectorXd> a_map( a.data(), n );
Map<VectorXd> b_map( b.data(), n );
SparseMatrix<double> As( n, n );
As.reserve( nnz );
As.makeCompressed();
Map<SparseMatrix<double>> As_map( n, n, nnz,
    As.outerIndexPtr(), As.innerIndexPtr(), As.valuePtr(), nullptr );
Matrix2d A2;
Vector2d x2;
Vector2d b2;
Map<Matrix2d> A2_map( A2.data() );
Map<Vector2d> x2_map( x2.data() );
Map<Vector2d> b2_map( b2.data() );
```

### Test A: coefficient wise operations

None of the following create temporaries:

```
x = a + b;
x.array() = a.array() / b.array();
x_map.array() = a_map.array() / b_map.array();
```

### Test B: Dense Matrix-Vector product

Both the following create 1 temporary with size n:

```
y.noalias() = A * x + b;
y_map.noalias() = A_map * x_map + b_map;
```

To avoid it you should do:

```
y.noalias() = A.lazyProduct( x ) + b;
y_map.noalias() = A_map.lazyProduct( x_map ) + b_map;
```

Both the following create 1 temporary with size n:

```
y.noalias() = A.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>() * x + b;
y_map.noalias() = A_map.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>() * x_map + b_map;
```

To avoid it you should do:

```
y.noalias() = A.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>() * x;
y += b;
```

and

```
y_map.noalias() = A_map.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>() * x_map;
y_map += b_map;
```

### Test C: Sparse Matrix-Vector product

The following creates 1 temporary of size n:

```
y.noalias() = As * x + b;
```

To avoid it you should do:

```
y.noalias() = As * x;
y += b;
```

The following creates 4 temporary of size (2, 2, n, 2):

```
y_map.noalias() = As_map * x_map + b_map;
```

To avoid dynamic allocated temporaries you should do (there are still 2 stack allocated temporaries with size 2):

```
y_map.noalias() = As_map * x_map;
y_map += b_map;
```

The following creates 1 temporary of size n:

```
y.noalias() = As.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>() * x + b;
```

To avoid it you should do:

```
y.noalias() = As.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>() * x;
y += b;
```

The following creates 6 temporaries with size (2, 2, 2, n, 2, 2):

```
y_map.noalias() = As_map.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>() * x_map + b_map;
```

To avoid dynamic allocated temporaries you should do (there are still 4 stack allocated temporaries with size 2):

```
y_map.noalias() = As_map.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>() * x_map;
y_map += b_map;
```

### Test D: QR solve with 2x2 fixed matrix

The following creates 5 temporaries with size (4, 2, 2, 2, 1):

```
x2.noalias() = A2.householderQr().solve( b2 );
```

The following creates 6 temporaries with size (4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1):

```
x2_map.noalias() = A2_map.householderQr().solve( b2_map );
```

### Test E: Sparse Matrix LDLT solve

The following creates 8 temporaries of size (n, n, n+1, n, n, n, n, n) :

```
SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
solver.analyzePattern( As );
```

The following creates 2 temporaries of size (n, n):

```
solver.factorize( As );
```

If *inplace* factorization is used (see [Inplace matrix decompositions](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__InplaceDecomposition.html)) then factorize method creates 1 temporary of size n. In this case explicit call of factorize method is useful only if some elements of A have changed but the sparsity pattern is still the same.

The following does not create temporaries:

```
x = solver.solve( b );
```

***Summing up:***

- *Coefficients wise operations don't create temporaries*
- *Dense matrix-vector product doesn't create temporaries if lazyProduct and
  noalias are used*
- *Sparse matrix does not provide lazyProduct*
- *Using Map more temporaries are created*

Regarding the above cases are there any tricks to better perform and avoid temporaries?